# Iterate over multiline string in Go

Tags: go

In Python I can iterate over a multiline string.

```
x = """\
this is
my multiline
string!"""

for line in x.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Can Go do the same?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) in Go which iterates over lines from an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader). The following example creates a reader from the given multiline string and passes it to the scanner factory function. Each invocation of [`scanner.Scan()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan) splits the reader on the next line and buffers the line. If there is no more lines it returns false. Calling [`scanner.Text()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Text) returns the buffered split.

```
var x string = `this is
my multiline
string`

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(x))
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error occurred: %v\n", err)
}
```

In the example, the for loop will continue until `Scan()` returns false at the end of the multiline string. In each loop we print the line returned by the scan.

Finally, we check for any error that might occur in the process.

https://play.golang.org/p/U9_B4TsH6M

Comment: You should check for errors. See the `bufio` example: https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to iterate over a multiline string literal as shown in the question, then use this code:

```
for _, line := range strings.Split(strings.TrimSuffix(x, "\n"), "\n") {
    fmt.Println(line)
}
```

<kbd>[Run the code on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8TVPHhvIPV)</kbd>

If you want to iterate over data read from a file, use [bufio.Scanner](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner). The documentation has an example showing how to iterate over lines:

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f) // f is the *os.File
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text()) // Println will add back the final '\n'
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

Comment: While this is simpler than the other solution, it should be noted that this will not strip the `'\r'` character if newline happens to be `"\r\n"` (might be the case if the string was read from a file that was edited on Windows). `Scanner` properly handles all valid variations of new-line characters.

Comment: @icza There is no need to strip `\r`.  [Return characters (`\r`) are discarded from raw string values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

Comment: I'm not talking about raw string literals, I'm talking about a file edited on Windows (where line terminators are `"\r\n"`), if this file is read e.g. with `ioutil.ReadFile()`, it will contain `'\r'` chars too. Also `'\r'` chars are not removed from non-raw string literals.

Comment: @icza I assumed that OP is asking how to iterate over lines in a string literal as presented in the question. Answer updated to clarify this assumption.

Comment: Notice that if the string ends with a new line character, this way will generate 4 lines, while the answer from Ben Campbell will generate three lines.

Answer (score 3):

I think using `bufio` is the best option, but if you do need to just split a
string, I think `TrimRight` is better than `TrimSuffix`, as it could cover any
combination of repeated trailing newlines or carriage returns:

```
package main
import "strings"

func main() {
   x := `this is
my multiline
string!
`
   for _, line := range strings.Split(strings.TrimRight(x, "\n"), "\n") {
      println(line)
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#TrimRight